# && logical operator won't work but || operator does

Tags: java, javafx, logical-operators

My && logical operator won't work and will always return false and returns the second condition as true. But it works really well for || operator. What am i doing wrong please?

I tried using || operator and it worked fine but i want to use the && operator

```
@FXML
private void loginFunction() throws IOException {

    String username = this.username.getText();
    String password = this.username.getText();

    if (username.equals("username") && password.equals("password")) {

        // This Code is used to alert the user of any information in case the username
        // and password is all correct
        Alert alert2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert2.setHeaderText("Login Successful");
        alert2.setTitle("Welcome");
        alert2.setContentText("Pleae Wait. You shall be redirected soon.");
        alert2.show();
    } else {
        Alert alert3 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert3.setTitle("Intruder Found");
        alert3.setContentText("Either your username or password is incorrect. Please try again.");
        alert3.setHeaderText("Enter the Right Details");
        alert3.show();
        return;
    }
}
```

I expect the first condition to return as true but it does not. This is not the case for || operator.

Answer (score 6):

Well this

```
String username = this.username.getText();
String password = this. username.getText();
```

means your two fields **are the same**. Change it like,

```
String username = this.username.getText();
String password = this.password.getText();
```

because the text in `username` can't be **both** "username" and "password" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String password = this.username.getText();
```

as,

```
String password = this.password.getText();
```